# Word 2010, Move cursor to specific text, replace the text with file content

Tags: vba, text, ms-word, find, cursor

I have a line of text that says "[EmbeddedReport]report goes here[/EmbeddedReport]".

I want to replace the "report goes here" with an empty string and put the cursor right after the [EmbeddedReport] marker.  I will then run the following code...

```
With Selection.InsertFile ('c:\Temp\Report.rtf')
```

That should put the text of the report between the markers.  I tried to locate the cursor with the following code.  It does not seem to work.

```
.Selection.Find 
.ClearFormatting 
.MatchWholeWord = False 
.MatchCase = False 
.Execute FindText:="report goes here"
```

Only problem is the cursor is not between the [EmbeddedReport] and [/EmbeddedReport] and the file is inserted wherever the cursor was located before the macro is run.

Answer (score 3):

you will possibly need to call `Find object` twice:

**FIRST-** to find the whole phrase `[EmbeddedReport]report goes here[/EmbeddedReport]`,
**SECOND-** to find a `report goes here` text within result of step first. Important- you don't need to replace that phrase- it will be selected and replaced with the text you import using `Selection.InsertFile method`.

Here is proposed code (tested for sample file):

```
 'FIRST- find [EmbeddedReport]report goes here[/EmbeddedReport]
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "(\[EmbeddedReport\])text goes here(\[\/EmbeddedReport\])"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    '...and select it
    Selection.Find.Execute

    'SECOND- find only text to replace 'text goes here'
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "text goes here"
        .Replacement.Text = " "
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .MatchWildcards = True
    End With
    'end select it
    Selection.Find.Execute

    'now you could insert your file
    Selection.InsertFile "c:\Temp\Report.rtf"
```

Comment: KazJaw That does get rid of the "report goes here" but the file still inserts wherever the cursor was when the macro starts.  It appears the cursor is not moving between the[EmbeddedReport] and [/EmbeddedReport] markers.

Comment: KazJaw...I'm sorry.  It was my fault it did not work.  I had not removed a bit of code above your code.  I still need to do some testing but I think your have answered my question.  I will mark it as the answer after I have a chance to test further.  I did not have to do the first Find only the second.  Thanks again.

Comment: Just now I see your first comment above. If you need any other help please add complete/more of your code to your question.

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to fix these kind of problems is to record a macro - and perform the tasks you need to move the cursor and highlight text, etc. - and then examine the code that the macro wrote to perform those tasks.  This will usually give you the insight to tailor your own code to perform the same tasks.

Comment: dav1dsm1th...To be honest with you that did cross my mind after I had already posted the question, but thanks for the insight. I appreciate you taking time to respond.

Comment: dav1dsm1th...I'm sorry.  It was my fault it did not work.  I had not removed a bit of code above your code.  I still need to do some testing but I think your have answered my question.  I will mark it as the answer after I have a chance to test further.  Thanks again.

Comment: I only suggested an approach... no code.  If it was @KazJaw that answered your question, please credit him with providing the solution.